# React competing async data loads

Tags: reactjs

In my React app (built using React-Bootstrap and functional components) I have a couple of places where data is loaded asynchronously. One example is the first page after login, where options are added to the sidebar component and notifications are added to the main panel. I'll include some sample code from the app, though I think my question is more conceptual.

The problem I want to solve is this -- when one async call complete, it seems to reset the state of the whole app, such that user interactions (exapand/collapse) in the side menu are lost, sometimes items from the side menu appear then disappear. Can someone offer a link to a good resource for learning how to properly isolate these async calls so that they don't have this kind of unintended side effect?

```
 const getNotifications = () => {
    const url = appData.endpoint + "/notifications?email=" + appData.userEmail + '&userId=' + appData.userId;
    fetch(url, {
      method : "GET",
      cache : "no-cache",
      headers : {
        Authorization : appData.token,
      }      
    })
    .then((res) => {
      if (200 === res.status) {
        res.json().then((data) => {
          setAppData({ 
            ...appData, 
            notifications : data['notifications'], 
            referenceDate : data['now'],
          });
        });
      }
    })
```

Comment: You might want to provide a bit more context but here are a few things to check: ensure you page is not unintentionally reloading, also ensure data that controls the expand/collapse state of your menu is stateful and not redefined on every render

Comment: Your question is *off-topic* on [SO], for asking for recommendations for resources, books, tools, software libraries, and more. This is likely to lead to opinionated answers, rather than fact based ones. As a side note, you might want to check out [Preserving and Resetting state](https://react.dev/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state) and, depending on context, use [Jotai](https://jotai.org/), or other similar state mgmt solutions, `React.useContext` or lifting the relevant state in the component receiving the async data.

Comment: @tao yes, it's using useContext -- the setAppData is a dataStore function. Jotai may be the answer I'm looking for, reading about that now.